# How to stop the Maven after a specified project has been built?

Tags: java, maven

This is a similar (but opposite) question to [Can we start the maven build from the point where it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902322): Am wondering if there is an option to *stop* the build at (or after) a particular project. Something like a `--stop-after` option in the same vein as `--resume-from`?

**Use case:**
This would sometimes be a useful feature to me, e.g. to create a standalone JAR that is a dependency for other modules but has its own dependent modules that need to be built first:

```
    /------Parent pom------\
    |          |           |
Module 1 -> Module 2 -> Module 3
```

Here's a simplified example but illustrates the point: Let's say we have a parent pom.xml that lists modules 1, 2 and 3 that are each dependent on the next in that order. So to build Module 2, we need Module 1 to be built first. But we're only interested in building Module 2 and don't want to go any further once this has been done (Module 3 takes ages or does stuff we don't want to do e.g. rebuild the database). So here we'd want to run Maven from the parent director and both *resume from* and *stop after* Module 2.

Comment: Could you clarify your use-case? This really sounds like a XY problem: you don't want to stop the build.

Comment: @Tunaki OK, have added more details of the use case to the question.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for the duplicate link. Although `--also-make` looks promising it doesn't quite do what would be ideal since in the example case it would always look to build Module 1 before Module 2. `-projects` isn't ideal either as it requires all dependencies that need to be built to be manually specified. But guess this is just a Maven limitation...

Comment: Yes that's how Maven is: you can't build Module 2 without building Module 1 since it's a dependency and they both belong to the same multi-module project.

Comment: Cruel, was about to post an answer. You can define what modules are built per profile by defining the `<modules>` node underneath each `<profile>`. Change your `<modules>` element in the  root pom to only contain `module1` amd `module2` then define all 3 modules underneath the profiles you wish to build all 3.

Comment: @Tunaki Well you can with `-rf` if it's already been built...

Comment: @ug_ I thought about profiles also but I don't think it fits in this use-case. OP wants to build Module 2 or Module 3, in a sort of dynamic manner. We would have to define profiles for each scenario, which is really crumbersome